# Convert a haxe.Int64 to a Float?

Tags: haxe

How can I convert a haxe.Int64 to a Float?

I've got something like

```
var x = haxe.Int64.parseString("1000000000000");
```

and I'd like to convert that to a Float. I've looked in [the Int64 api docs](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/Int64.html), have found `fromFloat`, `ofInt`, and `toInt`, but there's no `toFloat` method in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot see that functionality in the Haxe standard library either, I checked `Int64` and `Int64Helper`.

However the MIT-licensed [thx.core](https://lib.haxe.org/p/thx.core) library does include an implementation, see below: https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.core/blob/master/src/thx/Int64s.hx#L137

```
using haxe.Int64;

class Int64s {

  static var zero = Int64.make(0, 0);
  static var one = Int64.make(0, 1);
  static var min = Int64.make(0x80000000, 0);

/**
Converts an `Int64` to `Float`;
Implementation by Elliott Stoneham.
*/
  public static function toFloat(i : Int64) : Float {
    var isNegative = false;
    if(i < 0) {
      if(i < min)
        return -9223372036854775808.0; // most -ve value can't be made +ve
      isNegative = true;
      i = -i;
    }
    var multiplier = 1.0,
        ret = 0.0;
    for(_ in 0...64) {
      if(i.and(one) != zero)
        ret += multiplier;
      multiplier *= 2.0;
      i = i.shr(1);
    }
    return (isNegative ? -1 : 1) * ret;
  }
}
```

Using the library method worked for me, tested on the JavaScript target like so:

```
import haxe.Int64;
import thx.Int64s;

class Main {    
    public static function main():Void {
        var x:Int64 = haxe.Int64.parseString("1000000000000");
        var f:Float = thx.Int64s.toFloat(x);
        trace(f); // Prints 1000000000000 to console (on js target)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why you copy/pasted thx.core's implementation, but I appreciate your answer, and didn't realize thx.core had what I was looking for.

Comment: @uvtc Glad to help. Copy-paste is so the answer remains useful even if the thx.core repository is moved or renamed in future.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can convert Int64 to Float yourself by combining high/low halves:

```
class Test {
  static function main() {
    var x = haxe.Int64.parseString("1000000000000");
    var f = x.high * 4294967296. + (x.low >>> 0);
    trace("" + x);
    trace(f);
  }
}
```

Here,
`4294967296.` is a float literal for unsigned 2^32;
`>>> 0` is required because the lower half can be signed.

Answer (score 2):

Or, for a naive conversion method, you can use:

```
var f = Std.parseFloat(haxe.Int64.toStr(x));
```

Comment: Naive... but the most reliable solution given here!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to use `FPHelper` class. It contains a set of methods to convert Int types to Float / Double.

```
import haxe.io.FPHelper;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var x = haxe.Int64.parseString("1000000000000");
        var f = FPHelper.i64ToDouble(x.low, x.high);
        trace(f);
    }
}
```

See https://try.haxe.org/#CDa93

Comment: Some caution about this, this doesn't do what most people would expect. It doesn't handle numerical values but packs binary representations of IEEE floating point numbers into 4 or 8 bytes. Useful for serialization, but not mathematical calculation.